# PDOStatement::execute, How to execute?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to execute this query?

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendancy 
          WHERE user_id = $user_id 
          AND date = '$date'";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Do you have database to connect to?

Comment: Yes, I have the database

Comment: Does the answer work?

Answer (score 3):

To `execute` you need to use the [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function. This usage of the `prepare` function also is not safe, each variable should be a placeholder.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendancy 
      WHERE user_id = ? 
      AND date = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($user_id, $date));
while($result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     print_r($result);
}
```